# ZipArchive won't modify a memory stream

Tags: c#, webrequest, memorystream

I'm trying to download a zip file and modify it before returning it. I expect the stream to be modified after adding additional files with ZipArchive in Update mode. However, it stays the same. What am I doing wrong?

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    string url = "http://www.dynaexamples.com/examples-manual/ls-dyna_example.zip/at_download/file";
    byte[] downloadedData = webClient.DownloadData(url);

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.Write(downloadedData, 0, downloadedData.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(stream.Length.ToString()); //911616

        ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Update);
        ZipArchiveEntry testFile = archive.CreateEntry("test.txt");
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(testFile.Open()))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("test");
            writer.Flush();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(stream.Length.ToString()); //911616
    }
}
```

Comment: `ZipArchive` is itself `Disposable`. Try `using` that before checking the result.

Comment: You need to close/flush archive so it writes data to the underlying stream.